# ¿Cómo hacer promedio de filas anteriores teniendo como criterio otra columna de la fila?

Tags: r, date, rstudio

Necesito para R sacar la media de un valor teniendo en cuenta los tres días anteriores a la fecha donde me encuentro. Es decir, teniendo esta tabla:

```
date unit_sales 
2013-01-10   1
2013-01-11   1 
2013-01-14   1 
2013-01-18   2 
2013-01-21   1  
2013-01-25   1
```

Me gustaría tener la media de los tres días anteriores a la fecha de la fila. En el caso de que no aparezca no considerarla.

El resultado que esperaría tener sería el siguiente:

```
date unit_sales Average
2013-01-10   1    NA
2013-01-11   1    1
2013-01-14   1    1
2013-01-18   2    NA
2013-01-21   1    2
2013-01-25   1    NA
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Graciasss

Comment: Bienvenido anasavilu a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Gracias pero está bien hecho, ¿no?

Comment: Por tu pregunta? si está bien, aunque le agregaría aunque sea una breve descripción de lo que hubieras intentado hasta ahora. Saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que `date` es algún tipo de fecha y no una cadena, siendo así, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
df$desde <- df$date - 3
df$media <- apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(df$unit_sales[df$date >= x["desde"] & df$date < x["date"]],na.rm = TRUE))
df

        date unit_sales      desde media
1 2013-01-10          1 2013-01-07   NaN
2 2013-01-11          1 2013-01-08     1
3 2013-01-14          1 2013-01-11     1
4 2013-01-18          2 2013-01-15   NaN
5 2013-01-21          1 2013-01-18     2
6 2013-01-25          1 2013-01-22   NaN
```

Detalle:

- Generamos una nueva columna con una nueva fecha 3 días antes de cada `date`
- Con `apply` aplicamos una función por cada fila que calcula la media de la selección deseada

Nota: este código se podría hacer aún más compacto, usando `sapply()` para evitar la conversión implícita a `character` de las fechas

```
df$media <- sapply(df$date, function(x) mean(df$unit_sales[df$date >= (x - 3) & df$date < x],na.rm = TRUE))
```