# ¿Cómo calcular la media móvil de tres años corridos?

Tags: r

[image: Aquí una muestra del promedio móvil que quiero hallar, digamos para el 12 de Junio de 2011, hallar la media móvil con los tres años inmediatamente anteriores, y así para cada día del año 2011]

Estoy tratando de hallar la media móvil de unos datos de contaminantes atmosféricos, y he visto que se puede con la función "filter" y otras opciones. No obstante, en los ejemplos que he visto, hallan la media móvil con un intervalo de datos determinado.

Quisiera saber, cómo podría indicarle a R, que halle la media móvil de cada día del año, junto con los 1094 días anteriores, es decir, con los registros de datos de tres años anteriores consecutivos, para cada día del año que voy a evaluar.

Aquí una muestra de mi data frame:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1041379200, 1041465600, 1041552000, 
1041638400, 1041724800, 1041811200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), site = c("AGUINAGA (S)", "AGUINAGA (S)", 
"AGUINAGA (S)", "AGUINAGA (S)", "AGUINAGA (S)", "AGUINAGA (S)"
), EnvAut = c("A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", 
"A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", "A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA", 
"A.M. VALLE DE ABURRA"), Latitude = c(6.2531, 6.2531, 6.2531, 
6.2531, 6.2531, 6.2531), Longitude = c(-75.568636, -75.568636, 
-75.568636, -75.568636, -75.568636, -75.568636), AveragingTimeHours = c(24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24), Year = c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003
), Var = c("PM10", "PM10", "PM10", "PM10", "PM10", "PM10"), Units = c("ugm3", 
"ugm3", "ugm3", "ugm3", "ugm3", "ugm3"), COD_DEP = c(5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5), NOM_DEP = c("ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", 
"ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA", "ANTIOQUIA"), COD_MUN = c(5001, 5001, 
5001, 5001, 5001, 5001), NOM_MUN = c("MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", 
"MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N", "MEDELL<cd>N"), 
    StationType = c("Fija", "Fija", "Fija", "Fija", "Fija", "Fija"
    )), spec = structure(list(cols = list(date = structure(list(
    format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), class = c("collector_datetime", 
"collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
"collector")), site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), EnvAut = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), AveragingTimeHours = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
"collector")), Var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Units = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), COD_DEP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), NOM_DEP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), COD_MUN = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), NOM_MUN = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), StationType = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hola Laura, tu pregunta es conceptualmente igual a esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344200/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-promedio-de-filas-anteriores-teniendo-como-criterio-otra-columna-de, reemplaza el 3 por 1094 y creo que debería responder este planteo. Cualquier duda me dices, pero yo la considero duplicada. Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta Patricio, intentaré realizarlo de la manera que indica la respuesta de la otra pregunta, y en dado caso que no me funcione, te estaré preguntando.